# Incorrect syntax near GO (Creating users based off login)

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I am trying to create a user in a database based off a login on the root sql server but I keep getting syntax errors. I don't see an issue in this simple query unless `SqlCommand` requires a different type of syntax than actual T-SQL in SSMS does.

```
 var cmd = new SqlCommand("USE " + databaseName + " GO CREATE USER [" + txtUser.Text + "] FOR LOGIN ["
                + txtUser.Text + "] GO", conn);
```

My connection string looks like this

```
private string GetConnectionString(string initialCatalog = "")
    {
        return "Data Source=" + txtInstance.Text.Trim() + ";User ID=" + txtUser.Text.Trim() +
            ";" + (initialCatalog != "" ? "Initial Catalog=" + initialCatalog : "")
            + "Password=" + txtPass.Text.Trim() + ";Network Library=dbmssocn;";
    }
```

I am not passing it an `initialCatalog`

I did try to remove the `USE` statement from the actual command text and instead pass the dbname to `GetConnectionString` method so as to set it as the initial catalog but then I get *login failed for user x*

I am assuming this is because the user is not on the given database. Given the fact that user *x* is a login on sql server with FULL rights, how can I create a user on a database within SQL server tied to this login with full rights?

**EDIT**
I am aware that my code is susceptible to injection attacks; however, this is an internal helper app that only I will most likely be using.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I ended up using andy's answer. Was hoping to get it all in one `ExecuteNonQuery` but it doesn't matter for a tiny app like this

Comment: `GO` is a feature of Sql Management Studio, it is not part of tsql. You must manually separate it in to batches by hand. You don't have to do seperate `SqlCommand` objects, you can re-use the same one just update the `cmd.CommandText` property then call `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: Also you may find [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) more reliable for creating connection strings than string containation, you may want to look in to it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's a great tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you execute both the queries separately

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("USE " + databaseName , conn);  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE USER [" + txtUser.Text + "] FOR LOGIN ["
            + txtUser.Text + "]", conn);  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: There is no need to create new commands, just update the `CommandText` property.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that is what I did :)